# create external link to javascript filter link "created with Isotope"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-isotope

I have a page on my website that has a JavaScript filter (called Isotope) to display specific items on a page when you click a link on that page.

I would like to create an external link that will go to that page AND select one of the filter items.

I was thinking it should be something like:
mysite.com/page.html#filter.3

I'm obviously way off however I'm not sure where to even start looking to find a solution.

The filter presets look like the code below.

```
<div id="filters">
    <ul class="option-set" data-option-key="filter">
        <li><a href="#filter" class="selected" data-option-value="*">All</a></li>
        <li>/</li>
        <li><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".2">Adults</a></li>
        <li>/</li>
        <li><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".3">Youth</a></li>
        <li>/</li>
        <li><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".4">Kids</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: parse location.href.slice(1) into your href and data-attrib value, then use $(chunks).click() to "select" it.

Comment: Hmm, I sorta feel that but I'm not getting my head wrapped completely around it. can please expand a little?

Comment: Assuming you use Isotope v1, there's an [article](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/hash-history-jquery-bbq.html) and a [demo](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/hash-history.html#filter=.metal&sortBy=name) for exactly what you're after using the [jQuery BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) plugin.